# Transferring data through tcp sockets using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, hl7

I have a simple node application that sends data through tcp sockets. Essentially it’s two node applications a sender and a receiver, or a client and server. I can open two terminal shells on my localhost and see data transferring though tcp sockets, so I know it works. I want to send data from my localhost to my server with these applications but I can’t figure it out.. wether its the ip address routing or if I have to open tcp ports or disable firewalls, not sure. here's what the server and client apps look like when I can successfully send data on my localhost. I want to use this client app on my localhost and host the server app on my centos server and transfer data, is this possible?

```
  /*** TCP Client ***/
    /* Dependencies */
    var fs = require('fs');
    var hl7 = require('simple-hl7');
    /* Build TCP Server */
    var server = hl7.Server;
    var tcpClient = server.createTcpClient();
    /* Connection */
    tcpClient.connect('127.0.0.1', 6969);
    /* Get XML  */
    var msg = fs.readFileSync('./data/example.xml').toString();
    /* Send Message */
    setTimeout(function() {
        tcpClient.send(msg, function(ack) {
          console.log("ACK: ",ack.toString());
          console.log("\nsuccessful transfer");
          tcpClient.close();
        });
    }, 500);
```

the server can be found here. [click here](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/148120/A-simple-node-js-HL7-MLP-server--Saves-m)
but heres the config code..

```
/*
    Config class
    vars:
    baseFolder: Where to save the messages
    port      : What port to listen on
    ip        : what ip to listen on
*/
var Config = new function() {
    this.baseFolder = "data";
    this.port = 6969;
    this.ip = '127.0.0.1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcouce it is possible. Set server's IP and listening port in client. Then since client gonna connect to server, you will have to open this port on the server in both directions. And then just connect.

Basically here `tcpClient.connect('127.0.0.1', 6969);` Instead of 127... should be server's real external IP address.

Comment: Of course this was my first instinct but It isn't working for me. I'm guessing it's because the correct ports aren't open? How could I check this on my mac and my centos server? Do I need to use nginx as a webserver ? @Sergey Yarotskiy

Comment: This question has nothing to do with node.js and code. Ask another one, or just use google to find how to check if certain port opened or not.